# React JS TypeError - this is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
<select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange} size={5}>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>

changecountry(value){
 //some code here
}
handlechange = (event) => {
  let value = event.target.value
 setTimeout(function (){
  this.changecountry(value)
}
}, 300);
```

I am trying to call changecountry inside setTimeout function.
getting this.changecountry is not a function error
what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Did you bind `changecountry` ?

Comment: Use the arrow function for the callback of `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(() => {...}, 300)`

Comment: no.how to do binding?

Comment: @MWO where to add function keyword?

Comment: use `changecountry = (value) => {
 //some code here
}` arrow function and there is no need to bind event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your setTimeout to

```
setTimeout(() => this.changecountry(value) , 300);
```

`this` context will change inside `function(){}` in setTimeout. [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
is lexical scoped, will take reference from where it was created.

You can also bind the setTimeout callback,since `handleChange` is already an arrow function.

```
setTimeout(
  function () {
    this.changecountry(value);
  }.bind(this),
  300
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's usefull to explain why you're getting this error. It is because the wrong context is passed to the `handleChange` function. There are several ways to fix this error.

First option: here you pass an anonymous function thus keeping the context of your class. Else the context of the event handler function is passed.

```js
<select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} size={5}>
```

Or you could bind the `handleChange` function:

```js
// Change your original function name to "_handleChange" for better code visibility
_handlechange(event) {
  // ...
}
// Pass the current this context to your new handleChange function
handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
```

Comment: `handleChange` is already an arrow function, no need to bind it or again invoke it inside another  arrow function